# Generics in static methods

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

I need to add a method in a utility class with some static methods that parses things from a JSON string and returns an array of things.

Problem is that there are various subtypes of these things, so I created this method:

```
public static <E extends Thing> E[] parseThingsFromJSON(String body) {
    return parser.fromJson(body, E[].class);
}
```

How does the caller tell this method what `E` is? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass it.

```
public static <E extends Thing> E[] parseThingsFromJSON(String body, Class<E[]> eClass) {
    return parser.fromJson(body, eClass);
}
```

Generics is largely a compile time feature. This means its not available at runtime (with some exceptions)

In this case, to make to make the generic type available at runtime, you have to pass it as an additional argument.

Comment: Could you please point me to some explanation of this solution? I don't quite know what's going on and I'd like to ;) What's the purpose of this additional `Class` parameter?

Comment: @wasyl Hopefully my explanation has helped. Let me know what else you would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

From memory this is a similar problem to what you have when using Arrays.asList()

With this you do

```
Arrays.<MyOjbect>(new MyObject(), new MyObject());
```

or in your specific case where you are passing an array
eg

```
Arrays.<Integer[]>asList(new Integer[]{new Integer(1)});
```

The signature in the JDK for this method is

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a){...}
```

which is similar to your I think